# matlab: remove duplicate values

Tags: matlab, vectorization, duplicates

I'm fairly new to programming in general and MATLAB and I'm having some problems with removing values from matrix.

I have matrix tmp2 with values:

```
tmp2 = [...      ...
        0.6000   20.4000
        0.7000   20.4000
        0.8000   20.4000
        0.9000   20.4000
        1.0000   20.4000
        1.0000   19.1000
        1.1000   19.1000
        1.2000   19.1000
        1.3000   19.1000
        1.4000   19.1000
        ...      ...];
```

How to remove the part where on the left column there is 1.0 but the values on the right one are different? I want to save the row with 19.1. I searched for solutions but found some that delete both rows using histc function and that's not what i need.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the solution with unique, and wanted to give a solution with loops. You can take a look to see which one is faster :D! The loop could probably be ameliorated...

```
clear
tmp = [0.6000   20.4000
        0.7000   20.4000
        0.8000   20.4000
        0.9000   20.4000
        1.0000   20.4000
        1.0000   19.1000
        1.1000   19.1000
        1.2000   19.1000
        1.3000   19.1000
        1.4000   19.1000];

ltmp = length(tmp);
jj = 1;
for ii = 1 : ltmp
    if ii > 1
        if tmp(ii, 1) == tmp(ii - 1, 1)
            continue
        end
    end
    if ii < ltmp
        if tmp(ii, 1) == tmp(ii + 1, 1)
            tmp2(jj,1) = tmp(ii, 1);
            tmp2(jj,2) = min(tmp(ii, 2),tmp(ii + 1, 2));
        else
            tmp2(jj, 1) = tmp(ii, 1);
            tmp2(jj, 2) = tmp(ii, 2);
        end
    else
            tmp2(jj, 1) = tmp(ii, 1);
            tmp2(jj, 2) = tmp(ii, 2);
    end
    jj = jj + 1;
end
```

Comment: If you think your loop is better than `unique`: show it using a small benchmark. Otherwise, just look at the code and tell me it is better than `unique` solution... Moreover, [It is best not to use `i` and `j` as variable names in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: The only way I see this could be 'better' is that it always gives the minimum value rather than the first or the last as `unique` would. It also does not sort the results but that can easily be achieved with unique as well.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this using `unique`:

```
>> [~,b] = unique(tmp2(:,1)); % indices to unique values in first column of tmp2
>> tmp2(b,:)                  % values at these rows
ans =
    0.6000   20.4000
    0.7000   20.4000
    0.8000   20.4000
    0.9000   20.4000
    1.0000   19.1000
    ...
```

By default, `unique` saves the *last* unique value it finds, and the output will be *sorted*. This happens to be what you want/have, so you're in luck :)

If this is *not* what you want/have, you'll have to tinker a bit more. Removing duplicates preserving the order goes like this:

```
% mess up the order
A = randperm(size(tmp2,1));
tmp2 = tmp2(A,:)

% use third output of unique
[a,b,c] = unique(tmp2(:,1));

% unique values, order preserved
tmp2(b(c),:)

ans =
    1.1000   19.1000
    1.2000   19.1000
    1.0000   20.4000
    0.7000   20.4000
    1.0000   20.4000
    1.4000   19.1000
    0.6000   20.4000
    0.9000   20.4000
    1.3000   19.1000
    0.8000   20.4000
    ...
```

which still preserves the *last* entry found. If you want to keep the *first* entry found, use

```
% unique values, order preserved, keep first occurrence
[a,b,c] = unique(tmp2(:,1), 'first');
```

Comment: I would recommend using `unique` with `SetOrder` = `'stable'` to preserve the order.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: true, although that option is only available in new Matlab versions (don't know which version exactly started to include it, but at least not in R2010a)

Answer (score 7):

use `unique` without `'rows'` option

```
[C ia ib] = unique( tmp2(:,1) );
C = tmp2( ia, : );
```